# prolog - generate list with random values

Tags: list, random, prolog

I am trying to generate a list with random values between 1 and 10, but when I run the code, I'm receiving "false"...

```
geraL(0,_).
geraL(C,Y):-
  C is C-1,
  random(1,10,U),
  Y = [U|Y],
  geraL(C,Y).


?-geraL(13,X).
```

Comment: I'm using this platform... http://pengines.swi-prolog.org/apps/swish/

Comment: @SQB yeah bad habit. :) It starts out as a single blip of a comment and expands to an answer...

Comment: `findall(U,(between(1,N,_),random(1,10,U)), Us)` - rare case where findall makes sense.

Comment: @false That deserves to be an answer in its own right, since it's a very useful pattern in general.

Comment: @false ...even though I've added a similar answer based on `findnsols/4`.

Comment: @SQB: repeat's answer is **far** better. And has the potential to be even more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll cover each issue individually:

- `geraL(0, _)` says that if you want zero random numbers, anything could be the result. I'm sure that's not what you mean. What should the result be if the number of elements is 0?
- You should have a constraint that says `C > 0` in your general case to avoid executing this rule when it's not desired
- `C is C - 1` will always fail because for any value of `C`, `C` and `C-1` can never be the same value. You cannot reinstantiate a variable once it has a value within a predicate clause, except through backtracking.
- Although `Y = [U|Y]` is allowed, it's a cyclical list definition (a list defined in terms of itself with an additional head element), and I'm sure that's not what you want, either.

If you fix these items, your program will work. The first two are fixed by using an auxiliary (different) variable. The last one is defining the base case correctly to associate the empty list with 0, not an anonymous variable.

```
geraL(0, []).   % Fix for item 1: zero values should be an empty list
geraL(C, Y):-
  C > 0,        % Fix for item 2
  C1 is C-1,    % Fix for item 3: use C1 for the new value
  random(1, 10, U),
  Y = [U|T],    % Fix for item 4: use T for the new value (tail)
  geraL(C1, T).
```

Comment: I had `geraL(0, []) :- !.` instead of the added condition of `C > 0`, but the latter is better, since it defines a constraint, instead of controlling the flow. +1

Comment: @SQB. Beware of [tag:prolog-cut]: it often makes code lose steadfastness. (It does not in this particular case.)

Comment: @lurker: did you know that exchanging the two clauses will: 1. make your code deterministic, no leftover choicepoint whatsoever, 2. make it even a bit faster in many Prologs since clause-indexing can be exploited?

Answer (score 4):

No need to write recursive code!

Simply use `random/3`, [`length/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32478496/4609915), and [`maplist/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) like so:

```
?- length(Zs, 13), maplist(random(0,10), Zs).
Zs = [8, 9, 3, 5, 0, 7, 6, 7, 9, 9, 2, 4, 7].

?- length(Zs, 13), maplist(random(0,10), Zs).
Zs = [1, 7, 7, 6, 2, 5, 2, 9, 9, 2, 0, 7, 1].

?- length(Zs, 13), maplist(random(0,10), Zs).
Zs = [4, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 0, 8, 3, 8, 5].

?- length(Zs, 13), maplist(random(0,10), Zs).
Zs = [3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 3, 9, 8, 3, 7, 8, 1, 7].
```

Note the impurity! We get different answers—at least, most of the time...

For reproducible results, write down the actual [prng](/questions/tagged/prng) method and its initial state, [random-seed](/questions/tagged/random-seed).

Comment: Clearly the best answer!

Comment: @false this is the best way to solve the original problem, jwhich makes it a great addition to the list of answers. But the purpose of my original answer was to directly address the OP's question regarding why their implementation didn't work.

Comment: @repeat, isn't it a desirable thing for a generator of random lists of numbers not to have reproducible results? :)

Comment: @lurker. Yes and no. But mostly no. Nonetheless, I *was* surprised when I learned that IBM had investigated the impact of altitude on transient failure rates (single-bit flips) of non-ECC dynamic RAM in the 1960s;)

Comment: Well, I guess I wouldn't say "mostly" no, but I could definitely see "maybe yes, maybe know, depending upon the circumstances" as in whether it was by algorithm/hardware design, or by accident. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in predicate [`findnsols/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findnsols/4) which finds at most N solutions.

This predicate can be used for the equivalent of a loop. Since `random/3` is deterministic, we need to add [`repeat/0`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=repeat/0) to the goal to make it repeat.

```
geraL(C, Y) :- findnsols(C, U, (repeat, random(1, 10, U)), Y).
```

---

*Also, please note that [`random/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=random/3) has been deprecated in SWI Prolog; it is advised to use [`random/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=random/1) or [`random_between/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=random_between/3) instead.

Most notably, `random/3` excludes the upper bound, so `random(1, 10, U)` will never yield `U = 10`.*

Comment: To me, using `findnsols/4` in this context does not appear as a reasonable choice.

Comment: `findnsols/4` is a combination of two quite unreliable abstractions: `findall/3` which has a whole bunch of problems w.r.t quantification and `call_nth/2`.

Comment: `random/3` may be considered obsolete by SWI, but `random_between/3` is not available out of the box with SICStus (details: https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002drandom.html). So if your code is to run with both SWI and SICStus, better keep using `random/3`...

Comment: Note on the mandatory `repeat/0` with anything random: only one `repeat` statement is actually used in a call stack, so I suggest placing `repeat` first before everything else, like `findnsols(C, U, (repeat, main_predicate), Y).`, where any number of random generators can be anywhere in `main_predicate`. In other words, don't write `repeat` in detailed code.