# Prolog Termination of Generated List

Tags: list, prolog, clpfd, non-termination

```
N #>= 0, N #< 3, length(Ls, N), false.
```

The expression above does not terminate when posted on the swi prolog terminal.

I have tried exchanging the order of goals.

```
length(Ls, N), N #>= 0, N #< 3,  false.
```

and

```
length(Ls, N), N >= 0, N < 3, false.
```

I am using SWI-Prolog version 8.4.3 for x86_64-linux

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32478496/772868) for a definition that does terminate in that case.

Answer (score 1):

N is still var at that point. Use instead (if you really want to use clpfd - I'm not seeing a reason):

```
?- N #>= 0, N #< 3, label([N]), length(Ls, N), false.
false.
```

Comment: Thanks. The version without clpfd still does not terminate. `?- length(Ls, N), N<10, false.` Sorry for the noob question, I am still trying to understand the conditions for termination in prolog.

Comment: That's because `length` would be incrementing N into infinity. Use e.g. `between(1, 9, N)` *before* `length`.

Comment: Great. `between` will work for me

Answer (score 0):

> length(Ls, N), N >= 0, N < 3, false.

This will count up N trying different values until all the conditions are true, but `false` is never true.

So this is "count until false is true", which is "count forever", an infinite loop.

Comment: Don't blame it on `false`! `length(Ls,N)` alone does not terminate after all.